# How to avoid redirect were called multiple times in this action in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a each iterator and inside

```
  respond_with requisites, location: url_of_return
```

How to avoid this error: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by having that line in a loop? You can only render one page or issue one redirect per request. What do you expect to happen in a loop that the user is redirected to multiple URLs at the same time?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: I am sorry, but your edit doesn't make it any clearer. You have a couple of `users_ids` and for each `user_id` you determine some `url_of_return`. But a controller can only return to one URL. That means you have to pick one URL to return to. Where do you want to return to if there are different URLs calculated? To the first? The last? A random one?

Comment: it's the same url, but i need to add many users and need to put this inside loop

Comment: it would be the last url

Comment: When you always want to redirect to the last generated URL then just move the `respond_with` outside of the `each` interation, for example, right after the `end`.

Comment: if i move outside i lost schedule

Comment: You will not lose the last value assigned to `schedule` and `url_of_return` when you initialize those variables, for example with `nil`,  before you enter the `each` block.